# Can a Playstation 4 be used simultaneously while remote playing with a Vita?

Tags: ps-vita, ps4

I am interested in buying a PS4 and have a question related to remote play: If I were to remote play with the Playstation 4, could another person be playing it separately as well? For example, could I be streaming Need for Speed Rivals to my Vita, while say my brother plays Knack?

Obviously this couldn't be done with disc based games, but would it be possible to have two users doing different things simultaneously. Also, if this could be possible, would it allow to different PSNs to be logged in at the same time?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I know that a PS3 pretty much disables itself when going into Remote Play mode. Plus, playing two games at the same time will probably require twice the resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Only one user can use the system at a time.

While multiple users can be logged in, the Vita will display the same as the current view on the TV, and if the Vita user isn't the one with control (you get it from pressing the PS button on the Vita if another user has logged into the console), it can't do anything but watch.

You can't be signed into the same account on both.

Comment: Okay, well that makes sense. However, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by having multiple logged in. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I think what TZHX is trying to say is, if you're logged into your Vita with your account named Sam, and remote play to the PS4 which is logged in as Joe. You are playing on the PS4 as Joe. You can't be logged into the PS4 and Sam and Joe at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

What they mean is you and your brother can both be signed in on the ps4 but only one can be in control at a time. Like my fiance signs in to play games and if I want to play with him if the game allows for same screen multiplayer I sign into my account so I play as me and get my trophies. Also I play my Spotify on the ps4 while he plays his games.